# Security error whens scraping ticketing website

Tags: python, security, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape a ticketing website for a festival to be notified when a new ticket is available (Note: I am not attempting to illegally buy this ticket through automation).

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.moshtix.com.au/v2/event/splendour-in-the-grass/103360', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
print(html)
```

and here is the following error:

```
lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I've tried using the answers from related questions with the same error code but all have failed.

Comment: Do you get the same result when you use curl with that user agent?

Comment: Haven't tried, don't know how..

Answer (score 1):

Use a more complete user agent, many websites will block bots if the user agent doesn't match a known 'real' user agent.

Try

```
 headers={'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36'}
```

Comment: Great to hear! Select the green check mark next to my answer to mark your question solved.